# How to find corrupted PDF files from the command line efficiently?

Tags: command-line, pdf

I found a corrupted PDF file that gives me the following message when trying to open the file in Adobe Acrobat Reader:

```
There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.
```

How can I use the command line to find other corrupted PDF files?

One thing I tried that works was to use Ghostscript to convert the file to Postscript with the `ps2pdf`. Ghostscript correctly throws an error when it tries to convert the corrupted file.

The problem is there are a lot of these PDFs and the file size takes a long time to check with `ps2pdf`.

I also tried the Linux `file` command. This correctly returns the file type as PDF but doesn't mention whether or not the file is corrupt.

Is there a reliable and efficient method to check to see if a PDF file is corrupt?

**EDIT**

Here is data about the Ubuntu distribution I am using:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
```

It is Ubuntu server found on AWS.

Comment: @K7AAY thank you, I just added details about my distribution in my question.

Comment: Isn't `ps2pdf` supposed to convert from `ps` to `pdf`? Don't mean the reverse action? Is the corruption report any faster with `pdftotext`?

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes, you are right, I meant pdf2ps in my question. I don't know if I should correct it. I think I found the answer to what I was looking for here https://superuser.com/questions/580887/check-if-pdf-files-are-corrupted-using-command-line-on-linux